# jQuery modal will not close in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have added two links inside the dialog box which when clicked I would like to close the modal. This works fine in all browsers so far except IE7.

Here is the code to close:

```
function idConfirm(){
   $('#dialog-modal a').click(function(){
   $('#dialog-modal').dialog('close');
   });
}
```

Comment: _IE7_ Really??? stop beating dead horses pal, update :)

Comment: Tell that to the corporation that does not want to update their infrastructure due to lack of testing resources... Real life, pal. IE6 until a year ago, now IE8

Comment: Is this using jQuery UI's dialog widget?

Comment: Yes, it is using jQuery UI

Comment: Could you post more of your code? I tested with the IE7 browser mode in IE10 and did not encounter any problems.

Comment: How are you calling `idConfirm`? Unless that function is called, the `click` handlers on `#dialog-modal a` elements won't be set up and so clicking them won't close it. Perhaps there's something wrong with calling that function in IE7? I actually just went through a slew of different browser testing (using VMs to run actual older IE versions) with a jQuery UI dialog I had made last night, and it worked in IE7 with the dialog in modal mode. Heck, it even worked in IE6, even though the styling was fubar. And agreed on the more code request, that should help.